# bash case stmt - pattern not matching

Tags: arrays, bash, indexing, case, variable-assignment

This conundrum is stumping me.  Why can't bash's case stmt match the pattern variable and properly assign the array's index value to the command variable?

Script Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function run() {
    local       command SearchPattern="a2522866d08d848dd99b5997ad08eb936f68ce91"
    local -A    shaCommands=(
                    ['md5sum']=32
                    ['sha1sum']=40
                    ['sha224sum']=56
                    ['sha256sum']=64
                    ['sha384sum']=96
                    ['sha512sum']=128
                )

    printf "\${#SearchPattern}=[%s]\n" "${#SearchPattern}"
    declare -p shaCommands
    case ${#SearchPattern} in
        ${shaCommands['md5sum']} ) command="${!shaCommands['md5sum']}" ;;
        ${shaCommands['sha1sum']} ) command="${!shaCommands['sha1sum']}" ;;
        ${shaCommands['sha224sum']} ) command="${!shaCommands['sha224sum']}" ;;
        ${shaCommands['sha256sum']} ) command="${!shaCommands['sha256sum']}" ;;
        ${shaCommands['sha384sum']} ) command="${!shaCommands['sha384sum']}" ;;
        ${shaCommands['sha512sum']} ) command="${!shaCommands['sha512sum']}" ;;
        * ) printf "unrecognized checksum length=[%d] for [%s]\n" \
                "${#SearchPattern}" "${SearchPattern}"
            return $Fail
        ;;
    esac
    printf "command=[%s]\n" "${command}"
}

run
```

The output shows the case patterns are never matched - it should match on the ${shaCommands['sha1sum']} ) pattern - so $command is never assigned ...

```
${#SearchPattern}=[40]
declare -A shaCommands=([sha256sum]="64" [sha512sum]="128" [sha1sum]="40" [sha384sum]="96" [md5sum]="32" [sha224sum]="56" )
command=[]
```

Comment: `command="${!shaCommands['md5sum']}" ` What is this supposed to do? just command=md5sum if you want to, but better yet write a loop instead of hardcoding it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The case statement matches (you can confirm with `set -x`), but the assignment to `command` after the match is empty. `"${!shaCommands['sha1sum']}"` does not get the index of the array element like you want it to, because that expansion to get the indices of the array only works for `${!name[@]}` or `${!name[*]}` according to the manual.

```
${!name[@]}
${!name[*]}
If name is an array variable, expands to the list of array indices (keys) assigned in name. 
If name is not an array, expands to 0 if name is set and null otherwise. 
When ‘@’ is used and the expansion appears within double quotes, each key 
expands to a separate word.
```

In other cases, `${!var}` is an indirect reference (see [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)) where the value of `var` is used as the name of a variable to reference. `${shaCommands['sha1sum']}` has a value of 40, so `${!shaCommands['sha1sum']}` is interpreted as `${40}` which is not set in your command, so you get an empty string from the expansion.

You can simply use `command=sha1sum` instead. You're already hardcoding the key that you use to access the array, so your attempted solution isn't really any more robust than just hardcoding the command value.

Comment: Note that `${!shaCommands['sha1sum']}` is an indirection parameter expansion. Since the array value is `40`, this is equivalent to `${40}`. If there were a 40th positional parameter set, its value would be assigned to `command` instead of the empty string.

Comment: I understand the use of '@' and '*' to see array indices.  I don't see why my assignment will not work tho.  I'm not very clear on your explanation of indirection parameter expansion.  Of course I could make a hard assignment via "command=sha1sum" instead, but that defeats the purpose of utilizing the array and it's indexes and values.

Comment: 'set -x' doesn't confirm the pattern match.  + run
+ local command SearchPattern=a2522866d08d848dd99b5997ad08eb936f68ce91
+ shaCommands=(['md5sum']='32' ['sha1sum']='40' ['sha224sum']='56' ['sha256sum']='64' ['sha384sum']='96' ['sha512sum']='128')
+ local -A shaCommands
+ printf '${#SearchPattern}=[%s]\n' 40
${#SearchPattern}=[40]
+ declare -p shaCommands
declare -A shaCommands=([sha256sum]="64" [sha512sum]="128" [sha1sum]="40" [sha384sum]="96" [md5sum]="32" [sha224sum]="56" )
+ case ${#SearchPattern} in
+ command=
+ printf 'command=[%s]\n' ''
command=[]`

Comment: I can edit the answer to include more detail on what @chepner added because it's good info, but you're not getting a lot of value from your attempt to use the array. `${!shaCommands['sha1sum']}` already has a hardcoded `sha1sum` in it so attempting to extract the hardcoded key isn't any more robust than just hardcoding the value you want to assign.

Comment: `+ case ${#SearchPattern} in + command=` shows that you matched a pattern because it drops into a command assignment. It also shows that the command assignment is empty, meaning your expansion is empty.

Comment: I understand what you are saying.  The benefit is that utilizing the one defined array will (can) make it easier for maintenance by others in the future - all they'd have to do is add a new member to shaCommands(), like ['sha1024']=256, or similar.

Comment: Your array is backwards. Define `shaCommands=([32]=md5sum ...)`, and then you can simply write `command=${shaCommands[${#SearchPattern}]}` without the `case` statement at all.

Comment: Makes me wonder if I simply reversed the array definition to something like `shaCommands[40]='sha1sum`, then replace the case with a loop thru array indices, then on a match, assign command="${shaCommands[$index]}" ;;`

Comment: Thanks @chepner - we're on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Guess in this case indexed array is more handy:

```
shaCommands[32]='md5sum'
shaCommands[40]='sha1sum'
shaCommands[56]='sha224sum'
shaCommands[64]='sha256sum'
shaCommands[96]='sha384sum'
shaCommands[128]='sha512sum'

n=${#SearchPattern}
command=${shaCommands[n]}
```

Comment: even better assignment line can be simply `command=${shaCommands[${#SearchPattern}]}`

Comment: IMAO it's hard to read, some times it's better to split something in two(3,4...) parts rather than push in one complex command.

Comment: It's relative, huh.  Complex to you, simple to me - easy to read, plus added benefit of less code to execute, read, etc.